# hts accuracy of forecast and method of splitting training and testing

Tags: r, hierarchical-data, forecasting

I find 2 ways of training and testing hts and I am not sure which one is appropriate
1. In this question (link given)
[MASE Extraction Hierarchical Data ('hts' and 'forecast' packages R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971664/mase-extraction-hierarchical-data-hts-and-forecast-packages-r)
you have divided the time series into train and test and applied hts
2. In this question (link provided) 
[Hierarchical Time Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062141/hierarchical-time-series)
you are applying hts to the entire ts and then splitting into train and test.
My question is which of these is correct? please help

Also, I would like to know how can i check the accuracy of the forecast i make. That is, how far into the future can I determine that the forecast would statistically be appropriate using the hts model I choose to use. Any pointers to any articles or an example would be helpful. I would like to determine if i should forecast for 4,8, or 12 weeks ahead.

Thanks in advance