# I want to improve the accuracy(MAPE) for my hts time series forecast

Tags: r, time-series

I am working on hts time series forecasting on the same piece of code provided by Rob Hyndman ,on Level 1(2 nodes) and Level 2(5,1 nodes) . However the MAPE value I get is very high (More than 30 on most of the Nodes prediction )

I tried with the Tuning parameter using Arima model (for all the methods - top down , bottom up etc) suggested by Rob: [Hierarchical Time Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062141/hierarchical-time-series)

```
full <- aggts(data)
fcfull <- matrix(0, ncol=ncol(full), nrow=15)
for(i in 1:ncol(full))
{
  fcfull[,i] <- forecast(Arima(full[,i], 
                       order=fmodels[[i]]$arma[c(1,6,2)],
                       seasonal=fmodels[[i]]$arma[c(3,7,4)]),
                       h=15)$mean
}
forecast.full <- combinef(fcfull, nodes=data$nodes)
```

I need high accuracy MAPE approx. to be around 10

Answer (score 0):

I had some experience about forecasting using `hts`. In most of the case, the MinT reconciliation provide better out sample accuracy.

Changing the estimation of the covariance matrix (covariance="shr" or covariance="sam") has sometime proved to be useful.

Finally, you can try other models as `FUN` argument (`nnetar`, `arfima`...) in the `forecast.hts` function.